# Rearranging the rows based on a sequential unique values

Tags: r, tidyr

I have the following data set containing duplicate columns and I would like to stack them but in the following way. I can get the desired output with `bind_rows` but I would like to try it with `tidyr` functions:

```
df <- tibble(
  runs = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  col1 = c(3, 4, 5, 5),
  col2 = c(5, 3, 1, 4), 
  col3 = c(6, 4, 9, 2),
  col1 = c(0, 2, 2, 1),
  col2 = c(2, 3, 1, 7), 
  col3 = c(2, 4, 9, 9),
  col1 = c(3, 4, 5, 7),
  col2 = c(3, 3, 1, 4), 
  col3 = c(3, 2, NA, NA), .name_repair = "minimal")

df %>%
  select(runs, 2:4) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>%
              select(runs, 5:7)) %>%
  bind_rows(df %>%
              select(runs, 8:10))

# A tibble: 12 x 4            # This is my desired output in a way that column runs is a repeated number of 1 to 4
    runs  col1  col2  col3
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     3     5     6
 2     2     4     3     4
 3     3     5     1     9
 4     4     5     4     2
 5     1     0     2     2
 6     2     2     3     4
 7     3     2     1     9
 8     4     1     7     9
 9     1     3     3     3
10     2     4     3     2
11     3     5     1    NA
12     4     7     4    NA
```

However when I use `tidyr` the `runs` is arranged differently in the following way.

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-runs) %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-id)

# A tibble: 12 x 4
    runs  col1  col2  col3
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     3     5     6
 2     1     0     2     2
 3     1     3     3     3
 4     2     4     3     4
 5     2     2     3     4
 6     2     4     3     2
 7     3     5     1     9
 8     3     2     1     9
 9     3     5     1    NA
10     4     5     4     2
11     4     1     7     9
12     4     7     4    NA
```

I would be grateful if you could let me know how I could rearrange `runs` so that the numbers are sequential and not like three `1` in a row and ...
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but could you not simply group by runs and use the row numbers to arrange.

```
    df %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("col"),
                   names_to = c(".value")) %>%
      group_by(runs) %>%
      mutate(grp_n = row_number()) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      arrange(grp_n, runs)

# A tibble: 12 x 5
    runs  col1  col2  col3 grp_n
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1     1     3     5     6     1
 2     2     4     3     4     1
 3     3     5     1     9     1
 4     4     5     4     2     1
 5     1     0     2     2     2
 6     2     2     3     4     2
 7     3     2     1     9     2
 8     4     1     7     9     2
 9     1     3     3     3     3
10     2     4     3     2     3
11     3     5     1    NA     3
12     4     7     4    NA     3
```

Comment: Dear @Ashley G thank you very much for your answer. It was a truly remarkable and elegant way of handling this problem and you indeed taught me something valuable. I honestly didn't know about `.value` sentinel for `names_to` argument. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `split.default` :

```
data.frame(runs = df$runs, 
           sapply(split.default(df[-1], names(df)[-1]), unlist),row.names = NULL)

#   runs col1 col2 col3
#1     1    3    5    6
#2     2    4    3    4
#3     3    5    1    9
#4     4    5    4    2
#5     1    0    2    2
#6     2    2    3    4
#7     3    2    1    9
#8     4    1    7    9
#9     1    3    3    3
#10    2    4    3    2
#11    3    5    1   NA
#12    4    7    4   NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much again dear @Ronak Shah, it was nice talking to you.
I only have one question if I may and would like to know where we should use `split.default` instead of `split` since using `split` here returns a different value.

Comment: `split.default` splits the columns of dataframe whereas `split` splits the rows.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a great solution and it taught me a great point.